# finding .src in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, regex

If I have below code of lines in javascript:

```
function handleMissingImg(ele) {
    ele.src = 'Images/default--icon.png';
}
```

I need to find all the .src tags in javascript and extract value "Images/default--icon.png", if the value has image extensions like .png, .gif, .jpg, .jpeg.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find all the `img` tags, with `src` attributes? What do you mean by extract? What are you doing with that data  afterwards?

Comment: You are repeating same question in a different manner: [YOUR QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521258/regex-to-find-src-in-javascript)

Comment: I am not actually repeating. Since Regex is not possible as was mentioned in the comments in my earlier question, I need to find .src image values like in the above case and need to replace it with subdomain url like "https://static.content.com/Images/default--icon.png"

I dont want to find img tags. I have regex to find img src="Images/default--icon.png" in .aspx pages, but in javascript, if .src is applied to any id, i need to find the image value inside it. In this case, its "Images/default--icon.png" and then replace it with the above subdomain url.